# .vertices array does not give the vertices in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, vertices

I am using OBJloader to load an .obj file in WEBGL , Three.js.
I want to access the vertices and faces of the objects but the geometry.vertices does not return the vertices positions and it gives me undefined.

Here is a piece of code:

```
 var tool= new THREE.OBJLoader();
 tool.load( '../obj/tool.obj', function ( object ) {
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xA0A0A0});             
            object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                   child.material = material;
                   console.log( "child" + child.geometry.vertices);} }
```

r.70

I am thankful for your helps in advance.

Comment: The loader is returning [BufferGeometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry).

Comment: I have checked some samples using geometry.vertices with OBJloader but it does not work in my code. Besides, i need to move the object later and update the vertices positions and also access to the faces. But it does not have access to faces in buffergeometry attributes.

Comment: Thanks, So much appreciate it , It worked perfect.

Comment: Good. Posted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This answer only applies to versions of three.js prior to r.125.**

If the loader you are using is returning `BufferGeometry`, you can convert the returned geometry to `Geometry` in the loader callback using a pattern like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( bufferGeometry );
```

three.js r.124